# Net::OpenSSH::Gateway->find_gateway fails when ControlPersist option is set

Tags: perl, ssh, openssh

I am trying to create a persistent gateway connection using Net::OpenSSH::Gateway. Below is the code snippet I am using for the same.

```
my %proxy_opts = (
 host => $host,
 port=>$port,
 password=>$password,
 user=>$user ,
 scheme=>"ssh",
 ssh_cmd => '/usr/bin/ssh',
 master_opts =>
               [ -o=>"StrictHostKeyChecking=no",
                 -o=>"TCPKeepAlive=no",
                 -o=>"ServerAliveInterval=30",
                 -o=>"ServerAliveCountMax=90",
                 -o=>"ControlPath=/tmp/ssh-master-%h_%p_%r",
                 -o=>"ControlPersist=yes"
                ]
);

my %gateway_settings = ( proxies=>[ {%proxy_opts} ]);
my $gateway = Net::OpenSSH::Gateway->find_gateway(%gateway_settings, errors=>$errors);
```

I get the error below. But if I remove the option ControlPath and ControlPersist the entire thing works fine.

> [ERROR ] unable to establish master SSH connection: bad ssh master at
>   /root/.libnet-openssh-perl/spangeni-j1.zscaler.-31930-744378, socket
>   owned by pid 31933 (pid 31931 expected)

Comment: Look [here](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?ShowHeaders=1;id=70561) maybe this helps.

Comment: I saw that before posting it. I don't have a wrapper around my ssh binary. And I have provided the ssh_cmd option too.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bug in the module. The module `Net::OpenSSH::Gateway` doesn't exist on CPAN, and the author already said that:

> I have not published it on CPAN yet because, even it is already
>   functional, I have found some problems with its internal architecture
>   that I want to solve first. -[Source](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=952230)

And also if you see the documentation of `Net::OpenSSH` you'll see that gateway is an experimental feature.

[image]

---

BTW what version of `OpenSSH` are you using? ControlPersist requires **OpenSSH 5.6** or newer.

Comment: I am using OpenSSH_6.1p1. Is there any other way to create a persistent gateway and make all openSSH connection go through this gateway

Answer (score 0):

If you have tunnels enabled on the gateway machine, you don't need to use Net::OpenSSH::Gateway at all.

```
my $ssh_g=Net::OpenSSH->new($gateway);
my $proxy_command=$ssh_g->make_remote_command({tunnel => 1}, $host, 22);
my $ssh=Net::OpenSSH->new($host,
                          master_opts => [-o => "ProxyCommand=$proxy_command"]);
```